# Could relativity have been proven without classical physics?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, terminology

Could relativity have been proven without classical physics?

What is the term for this, in the philosophy of science?

Comment: Nor could we have gotten Chemistry without Alchemy...  I don't think this question has enough content.

Comment: really? it is exactly to the point, isn't it?

Comment: Would you have meant to include getting Chemistry from Alchemy as a case of the same phenomenon?  If not, you need more question.  If so, the question is pointlessly lame -- everything has to be evaluated in terms of what went before.  Science can only leverage the explanatory basis that exists, even when it is pretty sure it is wrong, when it tries to give 'proof'.  Nothing else is an explanation.

Comment: well, what's the term for it? progress ??

Comment: Maybe, but along the path that it actually happened the observations from which it was induced presupposed the notions that only acquired meaning in the context of classical physics (momentum, energy, inertial frames, etc.). For quantum mechanics I do not see how analogous presuppositions can be removed even after the fact.

Comment: @jobermark I think what he means, and correct me if I am wrong MATHEMETICIAN, is something analogous to the invention of the lightbulb before the wheel. Is it possible to develop knowledge of quantum mechanics without an understanding of classical physics (historic reference aside)?

Comment: @Conifolds point is part of the reason why most paths forward are going to discover stuff in a similar order.  Definitions are part of theories, and even in a theory that is abjectly wrong like Alchemy, you refine definitions like 'acid' and 'burning' from normal terms of use to technically-usable vocabulary that can then subvert the basic principles of your discipline.  If we encountered the behavior of QM in the time of Alchemy, however clearly, we could not have nailed it down without a detour through Newton.

Comment: It seems clear to me at least from the comments, that no two readers can come up with the same meaning for the question. Some times less is better, and some times more is better. But here the direction of the less is not clear enough to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not at all. As with every scientific theory, relativity didn't come up from nowhere. Relativity is a response to some theoretical, predictive and explanatory failures of classical mechanics, like explaining some gravitational phenomena and the behavior of light. It even inherits some notions of classical mechanics (e.g. Newton's mechanics also included relative time and space, and Relativity ditches absolute time and space) and builds on them to come up with a better theory. 
As for the term for this in philosophy of science, I don't quite understand what you mean. Are you asking about progress in science?